# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.util.Base64"

Tags: java, android, base64

Using third party JAVA jar file for Android application, it has dependency on 'java.util.Base64'. So here I can not use 'android.util.Base64'.

While running the app I am getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.util.Base64"
```

As per some of the stack overflow solution, we should add this dependency in android gradle

```
implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10"
```

But still the app is crashing with same exception.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64 says `Base64` is "Added in API level 26". So if your phone is older than Android 8.0 Oreo, Android won't be able to find that class.

If you want to use the `Base64` class from Apache commons (the commons-codec import you listed), make sure you import `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` instead. Note the API for those two classes are not exactly the same.

Comment: Hi @Maurice, I appreciate your response ,but  we need to support from Android 5 (Api level  22), without changing the JAR file. do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way around it. If the library you use is using that class, it either means it is missing a minSdkVersion 26, or it is not meant to support older Android versions (assuming you didn't override the minSdkVersion in your build files). You will need to contact the developer of that library for support, or fork it if it is open source.